# Getting XMLNS name not found error though class exist in namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image]

I am trying to refer `IntegerUpdown` from `xceed.wpf.Toolkit` namespace . When I use object browser I could see `IntegerUpdown`  but while building I am getting the error:

> Error  15  The name "IntegerUpDown" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended".

Comment: Visual Studio often gives fake errors like that... have you tried cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: And restarting Visual Studio

Comment: are you working x64  ? 
Visual studio designer often gives unrelated errors when working in x64 mode.

Comment: just run the application. It will run fine, visual studio behaves like this sometimes,

Comment: IME, this specific type of error is valid. But without a good code example (or _any_ code example, for that matter), it's not possible to suggest a fix. It may be you just need to build the `WPFToolkit.Extended.dll` assembly, or it may be you are referencing an out-of-date version, or you may have some subtle mistake in the XAML. Or maybe the type is present, but not `public`. Or... There are lots of possibilities. If the error goes away after a reboot, great. But if not, you need to fix the question.

Comment: I have the same error. I make a new clwan project, add the toolkit DLL and the `IntegerUpDown` in the XAML code and get the error. The preview in the GUI designer throws a markup error too.

Answer (score 7):

WPFToolKit defined a alias or custom namespace http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit. Refer below.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFComm_Learning.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:tool="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <tool:IntegerUpDown/>            
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I get a *Does not exist in the namespace* Error. The funny thing is that the  GUI designer displays "Invalid markup" but when starting the application the IntegerUpDown is there.

Comment: Build once and then check designer. Hope it should work.

Comment: Build, Rebuild, Restart - all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this one, and it drove me crazy for the better part of a day. My app compiled and ran OK, but the designer couldn't display my UI - a real problem since I was still working on that UI.

Things I tried that didn't work:

- Clean and rebuild the app.
- Unload and reload the project.
- Restart Visual Studio.
- Reinstall with Nuget.
- Switch between Debug and Release configurations.
- Switch between x86 and x64 platform targets.
- Specify the namespace alias using an explicit namespace/assembly reference rather than the URL reference shown in [LightSwitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3258812/light-switch)'s snippet above.

Finally, after much gnashing, I discovered [this article](http://www.kodyaz.com/visual-studio/unblock-assembly-file-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx) that shed some light. In a nutshell, since the assemblies came from an external source (in this case, a [Codeplex project](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/129331)), Windows set the Blocked flag on each of the assembly files. To remedy this, simply right-click on each file and view its Properties dialog; if an **Unblock** button is shown on the bottom, click it to clear the block. (This assumes, of course, that you trust the provenance of those assemblies - *caveat emptor*.)

One additional step (not mentioned in the aforementioned article) may be needed. If your project has references to the problem assemblies that were created before you unblocked the file(s), you may need to remove those references and re-add them to refresh them.

Good luck!